# Twitter API, posting on two accounts, only one gets postd

Tags: php, twitter

I have a working code that posts on twitter account via APi, using codebird. However, for some reason only the first account gets posted to, but not the second. No errors. Here's the php code:

```
            function tweet($message) {
                global $consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesssecret;

                require_once('/home/curse/public_html/manage/twitter-php-sdk/src/codebird.php');

                \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("$consumerkey", "$consumersecret");
                $cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
                $cb->setToken("$accesstoken", "$accesssecret");

                $params = array(
                  'status' => $message
                );
                $reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);

            }

            tweet("$twextra $makelink");
            function tweet2($message) {
                global $siimconsumerkey, $siimconsumersecret, $siimaccesstoken, $siimaccesssecret;

                require_once('/home/curse/public_html/manage/twitter-php-sdk/src/codebird.php');

                \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("$siimconsumerkey", "$siimconsumersecret");
                $cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
                $cb->setToken("$siimaccesstoken", "$siimaccesssecret");

                $params = array(
                  'status' => $message
                );
                $reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);

            }
            tweet2("$twextra $makelink");*
```

Comment: Why don't you pull those global variables into the parameter of the function send_tweet($message, $consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesssecret) and then remove the need to define two functions. This will make testing easier.

Comment: So what does `$reply` contain in each case?

Comment: Thanks guys. As it happens at least 50% of the time though, it's not the code that's stupid, but me. Obviously I had used some wrong token etc.